# How to set focus on a div containing the image in lightbox gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a lightbox gallery which has a div with id inside-overlay which contains the image. Now I want to bind key events to it but the problem is that even after executing

```
$("#inside-overlay").attr("tabindex", -1).focus();
```

I have to click it once with the mouse to achieve focus. On a click it receives focus but i want to focus it straightaway without any mouse click so to have `keyevents` for gallery navigation.

The problem is that the gallery would be visible only by clicking on an image. So window.load will not work for obtaining focus. I have alsi tried to put an input so as to focus on input and get my work done but even that does not obtain focus using focus() function

Comment: Try executing your code at `window.load` event.

Comment: Sorry but it isn't working that way

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get any answer but eventually i solved my problem. Anything cannot gain focus until it's not displayed so what i did was i gave the overlay of lightbox a tabindex of 0 and when i showed the overlay using:                                         $overlay.show();                                                        I changed it to $overlay.show().focus();                  Since it had a tabindex of 0 it got focus and my problem was solved and i bind the keyevents to the overlay.  I answered my own question just because if there would be a learner who is new to development like me if runs in this issue it may help it.